# Authenticating Rails App w/ Soundcloud, Getting 401 Unauthorized Error: invalid_grant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, soundcloud

Forgive me if this is a stupid question, novice programmer here.

I am trying to use the Soundcloud API to authenticate users in my Rails 3.2.14 app. I'm using the code directly from the Soundcloud developer docs, like so:

```
client = Soundcloud.new(
                    :client_id => 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
                    :client_secret => 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET',
                    :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/auth/soundcloud/callback'
                    )

# redirect user to authorize URL
redirect_to client.authorize_url(:scope => 'non-expiring')
```

And when I GET the callback URI:

```
client = Soundcloud.new(
                    :client_id => 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
                    :client_secret => 'MY_CLIENT_SECRET',
                    :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:3000/auth/soundcloud/callback'
                    )

# exchange authorization code for access token
code = params[:code]
access_token = client.exchange_token(:code => code)
```

Everything works fine (I am taken to the Soundcloud page to give my app permissions) but when I am sent back to the callback URI I receive the following error:

```
SoundCloud::ResponseError at /auth/soundcloud/callback
HTTP status: 401 Unauthorized Error: invalid_grant
```

I've obviously googled this and the only suggestion made was that my token is expiring. That doesn't make sense to me because I'm not reusing the access_token later, I'm just doing the initial authentication. Just in case I included the scope => non-expiring parameter when I redirected to Soundcloud, which made no difference.

Any suggestions? Has anyone had success integrating Rails with Soundcloud recently? All of the resources I've found seem quite outdated.

Comment: I am using the Soundcloud gem in my app with good results. I follow the same process as you, so I am puzzled by that error. I ran into this error when I was trying to exchange refresh_token for an access_token. But using non-expiring token fixed it. I would check if client_id and client_secret are accurate. I would also print out 'code' to check that it is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, when I was not exchanging the :code for the access_token correctly.  Check your variables using [pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) and make sure your :code is not nil

its also shows up when the access_token has expired, I know you are passing in :scope => 'non-expiring', but perhaps it loses the parameter at some point